# CSS Not Affecting Blazor Server Rendered Component

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a "menu" component that I am trying to make live API calls from during rendering - thus it needs to be "server" rendered vs static. This is in the _Host.cshtml.

For some reason the CSS classes I am wrapping it with do not render when it's "server" rendered, but work fine when it's static.

```
<div class="main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion menu-shadow" data-scroll-to-active="true">
            <component type="typeof(AppFrdb.Shared.MainMenu)" render-mode="Server" />
        </div>
```

I tried "ServerPrerendered", in that case, the menu component appears, but none of the icons referenced in it appear (they are all also CSS based)

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you wish to render this component inside _Host.cshtml necessarily? I would suggest to try and render your menu component in a layout component like MainLayout.razor for example.

Comment: @GiancarloSierra sorry for the delay here. I tried moving the MainMenu component into MainBody, but the CSS is still not loaded BEFORE the component is loaded, thus the Menu still is missing icons/styling.